# Google Standard Navigation Drawer Fragment switching

Tags: java, android

So I'm new to using android development. I'm trying to create an app with a navigation drawer. I used the built-in Android Studio wizard to create a Navigation Drawer, which gives you a bunch of pre-defined code. The issue is that I cannot figure out how to switch fragments inside the main view. I know you have to use a FragmentTransaction, but I cannot figure out how to implement this.

The generated code for click handling inside the drawer is as follows:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {


    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}
```

I just can't figure out how to pass it the fragment layout or class name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I just can't figure out how to pass it the fragment layout or class name

You don't do either one. Instead you create an instance of the fragment and pass it in directly. This is what `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)` does. The easiest way is something like this:

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, frag)
        .commit();
```

For more complicated situations, you should consider writing your own `newInstance()` method in your fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Try the example available on Android website: [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Download the example and walk through it. Its pretty easy. This is how I built my first app with a navigation drawer.